# Evaluating a complex integral of two variables

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

In https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423124/expectation-of-complex-random-variable?noredirect=1#comment1087394_423124, I got a clue that the following integral could be computed with a suitable substitution.

$\iint \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta$

($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are over $\mathbb{C}$).

The hint is that the integral could be solved by diagonalizing the quadratic form. In that way we could get $\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}x^TAx\exp(-\|x\|^2)dx=\text{trace}(A)\pi^2/2$. Could someone help me preform the diagonalization in practice?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda(\mathbf{r}|\Omega)}{\partial^2\Omega}\right] = c_5\sum_{n \in I}\iint\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta
\end{align*}
where $|I| = L$ and
\begin{align*}
c_5 = -\dfrac{8\rho}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)^3(1-\rho^2)^2}.
\end{align*}

First of all, the integrand doesn't depend on $n$ so we are left with a constant in front of the integrals

\begin{align*}
c_5L\iint \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta
\end{align*}

The complex integral can be thought as four real integrals when the complex numbers are split into the real and imaginary parts

\begin{align*}
&c_5L\int_\mathbb{C} \int_\mathbb{C} \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{|\alpha|^2 - 2\rho\Re(e^{-j2\pi\Omega}\alpha\beta^*) + |\beta|^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha\,d\beta
\end{align*}

\begin{split}
c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{\alpha_{r}^2 + \alpha_{i}^2 - 2\rho\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] + \beta_{r}^2 + \beta_{i}^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i}
\end{split}

Consider first the real part
\begin{align*}
&\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] = \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_r\beta_r + i\alpha_i\beta_r - i\alpha_r\beta_i + \alpha_i\beta_i)\right] = \\ &\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + e^{-j2\pi\Omega + j\frac{\pi}{2}}(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right]  = \\ &\cos(-2\pi\Omega)(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \cos(-2\pi\Omega + \frac{\pi}{2})(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) = \\ &\cos(2\pi\Omega)(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \sin(2\pi\Omega)(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)
\end{align*}
Denote $\xi = \cos(2\pi\Omega)$ and $\psi = \sin(2\pi\Omega)$
and we get
\begin{align*}
    &\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] = \xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)
\end{align*}
Moreover denote $\lambda = -2\rho\xi$ and $\mu = -2\rho\psi$.
Now we can write the integral as

\begin{align*}
&c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right]\text{exp}(-\dfrac{\alpha_{r}^2 + \alpha_{i}^2 - 2\rho\Re\left[e^{-j2\pi\Omega}(\alpha_{r} + i\alpha_{i})(\beta_{r} - i\beta_{i})\right] + \beta_{r}^2 + \beta_{i}^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}) \,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i} = \\ &c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right)\text{exp}(-\dfrac{\alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2 - 2\rho\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) - 2\rho\psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}\,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i}
\end{align*}

Denote by $\delta = \dfrac{1}{(\sigma_s^2 + \sigma_w^2)(1-\rho^2)}$ and we get

\begin{align*}
    &c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right)\text{exp}(-\delta(\alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2  - 2\rho\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) - 2\rho\psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2))\,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i}
\end{align*}

Now we can interpret the quadratic forms with symmetric matrices
as follows:
\begin{align*}
    \xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r & \alpha_i & \beta_r & \beta_i \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0 & \frac{\xi}{2} & -\frac{\psi}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} \\
    \frac{\xi}{2} & \frac{\psi}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r \\ \alpha_i \\ \beta_r \\ \beta_i \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2 + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2 = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r & \alpha_i & \beta_r & \beta_i \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_r \\ \alpha_i \\ \beta_r \\ \beta_i \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Denote by $S = \begin{pmatrix}  0 & 0 & \frac{\xi}{2} & -\frac{\psi}{2} \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} \\
    \frac{\xi}{2} & \frac{\psi}{2} & 0 & 0 \\ -\frac{\psi}{2} & \frac{\xi}{2} & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}$ and with $B = \delta(-2\rho S + I)$.
Now the integral becomes

\begin{align*}
    &c_5L \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R} \left(\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) + \psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i)\right)\text{exp}(-\delta(\alpha_r^2 + \alpha_i^2 - 2\rho\xi(\alpha_r\beta_r + \alpha_i\beta_i) - 2\rho\psi(\alpha_i\beta_r - \alpha_r\beta_i) + \beta_r^2 + \beta_i^2))\,d\alpha_{r}\,d\alpha_{i}\,d\beta_{r}\,d\beta_{i} = \\
    &c_5L \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} xSx^Te^{-xBx^T}\,dx
\end{align*}

Since $B$ is a symmetric matrix, it can be diagonalized with an orthogonal matrix. Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors with Mathematica and the diagonalization becomes: $B = P^TDP$, where
\begin{align*}
&D = \delta\begin{pmatrix} 1-\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1-\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1+\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1+\sqrt{\rho^2\xi^2 + \rho^2\psi^2}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&P = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}\begin{pmatrix}
-\psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & 0 & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) \\
\xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) & 0 \\
\psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & -\xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & 0 & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) \\
-\xi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & -\psi\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2)} & \rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2) & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Since $P$ is orthogonal, we have $PP^T = P^TP= I$. Also the diagonal matrix $D$ can be split into a product of two diagonal matrices with square root entries $D = \sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}$. A little bit of algebra yields $B = P^TDP = P^T\sqrt{D}\sqrt{D}P \implies \sqrt{D}^{-1}PBP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1} = I$. Now this means that if in the integral we substitute $x\sqrt{D}^{-1}P$ in place of $x$, we will get a Gaussian integral:
\begin{align*}
    &c_5L \int_{\mathbb{R}^4} xSx^Te^{-xBx^T}\,dx = c_5L\int_{\mathbb{R}^4} x\sqrt{D}^{-1}PS(x\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)^Te^{-x\sqrt{D}^{-1}PB(x\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)^T}|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\,dx = \\ &c_5L\int_{\mathbb{R}^4} x\sqrt{D}^{-1}PSP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1}x^Te^{-x(\sqrt{D}^{-1}PBP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1})x^T}|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\,dx = c_5L|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx
\end{align*}
And here we denoted $A = \sqrt{D}^{-1}PSP^T\sqrt{D}^{-1} = \\ \dfrac{\sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}}{2\delta\rho} \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{1 - \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \dfrac{1}{1 - \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{1 + \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{1}{1 + \sqrt{\rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}}
\end{pmatrix}$

First prove that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx = \operatorname{Tr}(A)\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}$.

Denote the elements of matrix $A$ by $a_{ij}$, where $i,j \in \{1,2,3,4\}$. Open the matrix product and by linearity of integration
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx =  \sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4
\end{align*}
Analyze the terms that are summed:
If $i \neq j$, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_i = 0
\end{align*}
by oddity of $x_ie^{-x_i^2}$.
And this means that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = 0
\end{align*}
If $i = j$, we have. Without loss of generality, assume that $i=1$ (just rename the variables and order the integrals accordingly).
\begin{align*}
    &\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}a_{11}x_1^2e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\
    &a_{11}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_1^2e^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\
    &a_{11}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)} \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_1^2e^{-x_1^2} \,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\
    &a_{11}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-(x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)} \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = a_{11}\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
We take here as facts that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2e^{-x^2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Now the sum becomes
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ij}x_je^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \sum_{i=1}^4\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}x_ia_{ii}x_ie^{-(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)}\,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4 = \\ &(a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33} + a_{44})\dfrac{\pi^2}{2} = \operatorname{Tr}(A)\dfrac{\pi^2}{2}
\end{align*}

Now it follows that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx = \operatorname{Tr}(A)\dfrac{\pi^2}{2} = -\dfrac{\pi^2\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}{\delta(-1 + \rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2))}$

Now the value of the actual integral can be evaluated by plugging constants in

\begin{align*}
    &c_5L|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}xAx^Te^{-xx^T}\,dx = c_5L|\det(\sqrt{D}^{-1}P)|\left(-\dfrac{\pi^2\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}{\delta(-1 + \rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2))}\right) = \\
    &c_5L\bigg | -\dfrac{1}{\delta^2(-1+\rho^2(\xi^2+\psi^2))} \bigg |\left(-\dfrac{\pi^2\rho(\xi^2 + \psi^2)}{\delta(-1 + \rho^2(\xi^2 + \psi^2))}\right)
\end{align*}

Notice that $\xi^2 + \psi^2 = \cos^2(2\pi\Omega) + \sin^2(2\pi\Omega) = 1$.

\begin{align*}
    -c_5L\dfrac{\pi^2\rho}{\delta^3\text{Sign}[-1 + \rho^2](-1+\rho^2)^2}
\end{align*}
As $\rho = \dfrac{SNR}{SNR + 1} \implies \text{Sign}[-1 + \rho^2] = -1$. Substitute the definition of $c_5$ also
\begin{align*}
-&\dfrac{8\rho L}{(\sigma_s^2+\sigma_w^2)^3(1-\rho^2)^2}\dfrac{\pi^2\rho}{\delta^3(-1+\rho^2)^2} = \\
&-\dfrac{8\rho^2\pi^2L}{(\sigma_s^2+\sigma_w^2)^3(1-\rho^2)^4\delta^3}
\end{align*}
Plug in the definition of $\delta$ and we are done
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{\partial^2 \Lambda(\mathbf{r}|\Omega)}{\partial^2\Omega}\right] = -\dfrac{8\pi^2\rho^2L}{1-\rho^2} 
\end{align*}